# Notification LED ARGB does not work

Tags: android, android-notifications

I've implemented a notification structure for my app:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.notif_icon, "New Message!", System.currentTimeMillis());
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
notification.ledARGB = 0xFFE60045;
notification.ledOnMS = 500;
notification.ledOffMS = 1000;
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notification.vibrate = new long[] { 500L, 500L };
notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

Vibrate and sound are OK but led does not tick the light.

What is the problem??

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Perhaps your device is not using the LED for notifications. That is up to the hardware manufacturer. Also, I *strongly* recommend that you use `Notification.Builder` or `NotificationCompat.Builder`, rather than creating a `Notification` directly, as the builder classes catch various problems for you.

Comment: Thanks, but if I set `notification.defaults` to `Notification.DEFAULT_ALL` or `|Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS` the LED shows green light!